# How to set a specific lines order in a one2many field in OpenERP7?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Is it possible to order lines in a one2many field by a specific column without modifying the original class order?

Let's put an example:
The model `res.partner` is ordered by the field ***name***. So, if you open a `res.partner` view, the rows are going to be ordered by their name.

Now, I'm in a view of other model. This model has a one2many field pointing to `res.partner`, this means that I'm seeing a list of partners, and they're ordered by name too.

Can I always see this last list ordered by other column like for example ***email***, but keeping the order by name in `res.partner` views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to manage this, downloading this module:

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/7.0/one2many_sorted/

Then, I overrided the one2many whose order I want to alter, in my case the field was child_ids, and I wanted it to be ordered by email:

'child_ids' : one2many_sorted.one2many_sorted(
    'res.partner',
    'parent_id',
    'Contacts',
    order='email',
)

Note that the only different between this field and the one2many is the param order (you can use a couple new more though, search and set).

I also imported the library at the top of the file:

import one2many_sorted

Now, I'm seeing the tree and kanban of res.partner ordered by name, but this one2many is ordered by email. Great!