# Ordering field by XML in OpenERP v.6

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have two inherited view form purchase.order.line and I want the field in that tree view is sorted by name, and the other one is sorted by create_date

If I'm using this in the .py file, both view will be affected

```
_order = 'name, create_date'
```

So I'm trying to make the order at XML file
Is it possible?
By the way I am using OpenERP V.6

Comment: Odoo v6 doesn't exist. The name is OpenERP v6

Comment: It's not possible to make the order in xml in that version. But, if for example you want to order only a `one2many` tree you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350610/how-to-set-a-specific-lines-order-in-a-one2many-field-in-openerp7)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a specific order in a view using the `default_order` attribute.

```
<tree default_order="name, create_date">
```

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html).

*EDIT: I'm not sure this is available for Openerp 6.*

Comment: Yes that only works in Odoo v8, is it possible to do it on the py file?

Comment: No, it would affect all views.